# Nav with section titles inside

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup

I have a nav, normally I would use a ul for markup but inside the structure this time I have sub titles, please note not all sections have sub titles:

```
- News
- Articles
- Products

Archive
- News
- Articles

Info
- Contact
- Terms & Conditions
```

What would be the way to mark this up?

I was thinking a ul for the first block that does not have a title then a dl for the sections that do have a title. Would this be semantically correct?

Comment: If you really care about semantic markup, then don’t make the mistake of starting with “this is how I want it to _look_”. If these are three “sections” of navigation, then why should not each and every one of them have a title? (Whether you want to _show_ those titles to the user for each and every section, is a totally different question.) So, that gives you a common structure for all three sections – and then using nested lists, as @Miam84 already suggested in their answer, makes a lot of sense. (For sure a lot more than arbitrary division in unordered list and definition lists would make.)

Comment: It depends on how many links/sections the `nav` has. Is this a realistic example, or do you have many many more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ul` elements can be nested

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>Archive
   <ul>
    <li>News</li>
    <li>Articles</li>
   </ul></li>
  <li>Info 
  ...
 </ul>
</nav>
```

**update**

As your `nav` is a list of categories with sub-categories, nested `ul` seems to be better because `dl` is a list of definition used for pair (like `title -> description`).

see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: Yes, that's not the question.